# Expand [conv-neural-network] to [convolutional-neural-networks]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag length limit is now expanded to 35 characters.

This means that [conv-neural-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) can be expanded to [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done - a [tag synonym](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) has been created and [conv-neural-network](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) has been merged into [convolutional-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolutional-neural-networks), thereby updating all existing questions. This has the added benefit of making the tag name consistent with all the other pluralized ones.

Comment: This might warrant an additional post, but isn't [tag:cnn] a synonym of [tag:convolutional-neural-networks]?

Comment: @wythagoras Yes, on the whole [cnn] is indeed just a shortened version of the latter, though there was one question that used the former to refer to "cellular neural network," which I just edited. I think the discussion of whether and how to synonymize and/or rename [cnn] would indeed merit a new meta question.